# freecodecamp react renderToServer

Tags: reactjs

I can't figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong here. Only error I receive is "The App component should render to a string using ReactDOMServer.renderToString."  Being the last exercise in the section I'm sure I'm way over simplifying it.

[Link to the exercise](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/front-end-libraries/react/render-react-on-the-server-with-rendertostring)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }
 render() {
 return <div/>
 }
};

// change code below this line
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(App);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following:

`ReactDOMServer.renderToString(App);`

Should be:

`ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App/>);`

`App` is just a class whereas `<App/>` is an element or an instance of `App` class.

Comment: Thank you.  Can't believe I spent so much time on that.  I knew it was a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing **an element**, you are passing a **Component**.

`App` is not an element, `<App/>` is.

Try the following,

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App/>);
```

IMHO, I strongly suggest you to read and think carefully and not give up on early stage just for sake of passing the level.

Comment: Thank you.  I really didn't actually.  That's why I finally asked for help.  I knew I was missing something obvious.  And yes, it's quite obviously a stupid mistake.  I'm getting better at them, but it happens.